# WebDriver instance created on @BeforeSuite level throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, testng, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I've been using `TestNG` to create my `WebDriver` tests and so far this combination has worked flawlessly. However I've been bumping into a problem so far that have not yet found a way to overcome.

`WebDriver` is created on the first test of a group that has over 950 tests spread through over 100 classes. In order to avoid creating multiple browsers instances (since most of the tests are pretty short and starting a browser takes sometimes longer than the test itself) i tried declaring the driver instance on a `@BeforeSuite` (and also destroying the object on a `@AfterSuite`) level on the first test and reuse it afterwards.

However once it starts on a different class, I've been bumping in a `NullPointerException` when it tries to find the driver.

The code is posted on gist on the following link (https://gist.github.com/4530030). The line that accuses the `NullPointerException` is SecondTest.java:15

Comment: please do so. Actual code will help. I feel like it will be some typo or declaring the driver badly.

Comment: Had you posted the code ?

Comment: Code has been added to the newest revision.

Comment: Haven't looked at your code, but you need to keep the instance either in a static field, or use something like Spring's `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests` to keep some state (including the instance) hanging around between the tests

Comment: Static is not a option unfortunatly, since that some of the original tests actually have to run in parallel and will not share browser instances.

This is to speed up the smaller tests that end up taking more than half of the time only to open, logon and then do the test.

Comment: I think you should put the BeforeSuite and AfterSuite in the SuperTest class.

Comment: I will give that one a try, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Probably this is a bit late, but your driver object is not being shared by firsttest and secondtest.  Each of them have their own copies.  So, whatever gets initialized is one's own copy.  Whichever class would run first would work and the second class would not have it since it's copy is not initialized.  What you can do is to have a class which returns the same driver object when asked for it..

```
public class DriverInitializer {

private static WebDriver driver;

@BeforeSuite
public void setTestSuite() throws MalformedURLException {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
}

@AfterSuite
public void endTestSuite() {
    driver.quit();
}

public static WebDriver getDriver(){
    return driver;
}
```

}

Then have all cases call eg. firstTest calls

```
DriverInitializer.getDriver().get("http://www.google.com");
```

Secondtest calls

```
DriverInitializer.getDriver().get("http://cnn.com");
```

So no matter who's calling the same driver instance would be returned.

The beforesuite and aftersuite need to be defined only once , they could be placed anywhere.just that in the above example they are referring to a private variable and hence i had to keep them in there..

Comment: I just need to make sure that having this static option won't affect my parallel tests.

Comment: If you want to do that as well, then you can try using ThreadLocal, you can use it as private static Threadlocal<Webdriver>, which would mean that if the tests are running in the same thread, then the driver instance would be the same

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I did look at your code.

The `driver` variable is defined in `WebDriverInit` class. But its hardly reachable by the `FirstTest` class. probably you will have to add this to the `SuperTest` class:

```
protected WebDriver getDriver(){
   return wdi.getDriver();
}
```

and at the beginning of the `FirstTest` and `SecondTest` you will have to define the `driver` variable for the class:

```
private WebDriver driver;
```

And in the Before

```
@BeforeSuite

public void setTestSuite() throws MalformedURLException {

startWebDriver();
driver = super.getDriver();

}
```

I am real Java newbie, so I can have it wrong. But I think the cause here is that you do not send driver down the First and Second test...

**EDIT**
In the SecondTest class there is no `@BeforeSuite` as it is in the FirstTest class. You do not start webdriver anywhere in the SecondTest class

Comment: Unfortunatly, not the case here. The super() ends up extending all the variables just fine. The problem is on the SecondTest.java, since the first one runs fine.

Comment: OK. I will post it also as edit, but in the example you do not call `startWebDriver()` method in `SecondTest` class

Comment: But it's supposed to be unnecessary since the `@BeforeSuite` is a configuration method called at the beggining of the test. If i insert a `@BeforeSuite` on `SecondTest.java` all im going to get as a result is two drivers starting at the beginning of the test, one of them on hold waiting the results for the second one.

Comment: then its beyond my poor programming skills. But I would bet on that "driver" variable is not properly initialized in the second test

Comment: I appreciate either way, i'm still looking for a light.

Answer (score -1):

In the first test you have defined a @BeforeSuite and an @AfterSuite. These create and destroy your driver object for the first test.

You second test doesn't have a @BeforeSuite or an @AfterSuite method so nothing instantiates the driver object hence you get an NPE

Add the @BeforeSuite/@AfterSuite to your second test.